# useCallback dependency array defeats the purpose of preventing re-renders when updating an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

The following React app displays a list of fruits. Each `Fruit` has a "add to fav" button which uses a `addFav` callback to add said fruit to a list of favourites in the parent. Passing in the `handleAddFav` callback causes unnecessary re-renders, so I wrapped it in a `useCallback` and `Fruit` in `memo`.

However the `useCallback` demands to have `favs` in its dependency array which causes the `handleAddFav` to be re-computed every time its called. This defeats the purpose of using useCallback to stop re-renders because now each `Fruit` re-renders every time you add a favourite. How can I solve this?

```
import { useState, memo, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Fruit = memo(({title, id, addFav}) => {
  console.log(title, 'rendered')
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <button onClick={() => addFav(title, id)}>add fav</button>
    </div>
  )
})

export default function App() {
  const [favs, setFavs] = useState([])
  const data = [{title: 'apple', id: '1'}, {title:'orange', id:'2'}
  , {title:'banana', id:'3'}]

  const handleAddFav = useCallback((title, id) => {
    setFavs([...favs, {title, id}])
  }, [favs])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing useCallback that sets an array</h1>
      <h2>Favorites</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setFavs([])}>clear</button>
      {
        favs.map(({title, id}, i) => <span key={id + i}>{title}</span>)
      }
      {
        data.map(({title, id }) => (
          <Fruit key={id} title={title} id={id} addFav={handleAddFav}/>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Describe what you mean by "unnecessary re-renders".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the function version of `setFavs` instead, so it doesn't depend on an outer variable.

```
const handleAddFav = useCallback((title, id) => {
  setFavs(favs => [...favs, {title, id}])
}, [])
```

For the more general situation - even if you did have a value that had to be re-computed, using `useCallback` could still reduce re-renders for the cases in which *other* values in the component change, but not the computed value. For example

```
const TheComponent = () => {
  const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
  const [num, setNum] = useState(5);
  const cb = useCallback(() => {
    // imagine that this does something that depends on num
  }, [num]);
```

If `cb` is passed down, even though it depends on `num`, `useCallback` will still prevent child re-renders  in the case where only `toggled` gets changed, and `num` stays the same.